# Angular throws Http failure during parsing for [URL] for HEAD request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

I am making a HEAD request. The request has 200 status code but Angular triggers the error

```
"Http failure during parsing for [url]"
```

I have set the `responseType: 'text'`. But still, I am getting the same error. What am I missing?

```
getNames(queryStr: string): Promise<string> {
    return this.http.head(endpoints.getNameUrl(queryStr), {responseType: 'text'})
      .toPromise()
      .then(this.handleResponse)
      .catch(this.handleError);

}

private handleResponse(response: string): Promise<string> {
    console.log(response)
    return Promise.resolve(response);
  }
```

Comment: responseType should be application/json only. Just give the output of endpoints.getNameUrl(queryStr)

Comment: Double check your server. It seems to work fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-client-1ah6vk?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts